# Show more button for text loaded from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to add Show more/less button to any text that has more than 100 characters. I use (this is in **index.php**):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var content  = $('.textcontent').html();
        var lessContent = content.substr(0, 100);

        if (content.length > 100) {
            $('.textcontent').html(lessContent).append("<a href='#' class ='showMore'>...</a>")
        }   else{
            $('.textcontent').html(content);
        }

        $('body').on('click', '.showMore', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('.textcontent').html(content).append("<a href='#' class='showLess'>...</a>")
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.showLess', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('.textcontent').html(lessContent).append("<a href='#' class='showMore'>...</a>")
        });
    });
```

So it worked for a normal element like(also in **index.php**):

`<div class = 'textcontent'>blablabla</div>` .

But for elements loaded from database using ajax, it doesn't work. (v this is in **index.php** as well)

```
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("pul").innerHTML = this.responseText;

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","home.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Now the **home.php**

```
echo "<div class ='textcontent'>$content</div>"
```

Does anybody knows why? Please help me. Thanks alot.

Comment: you need to bind controls again in the success method of ajax call

Comment: Can you be more specific, I've just learned ajax today :(